# I expect the program prints the numbers 0 to 99, but when I run the code I see 100 lines of 99

Tags: c++, object, pointers

I have a class `foo`:

```
class foo{
public:
        int i;
};
```

And a class `bar`:

```
class bar{
public:
        foo* foo_;
};
```

And a code similar to:

```
int i=0;
vector<bar*> fs;
while(i<100){
    foo f;
    f.i = i;
    bar* b = new bar;
    b->foo_ = &f;
    fs.push_back(b);
    i++;
}
```

I expect that each `bar->foo_` refer to a different `foo`, so when i have:

```
 for(i=0;i<fs.size();i++){
     cout << (fs[i]->foo_->i) << "\n";
 }
```

I expect the program prints the numbers 0 to 99, but when i run the code i see 100 lines of 99!!

why all pointers refers to the last object?

Comment: Why do you expect 99?  The code you've written should return 100 lines.

Comment: try making foo a pointer too `foo* f = new f`

Comment: `f` is no longer available after each iteration of the while ends. You're saving the address of the 'dead' object. I think that's Undefined Behavior

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `foo f;` are all technically dead, they go out of scope when the current iteration of the loop ends.

The reason your pointers are all to the last object is because the `f` allocated in the following iteration seemingly always overwrites the previous one, but *you can't rely on this either*. What you're doing results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is taking and storing away the address of a local variable `f`.

This is a no-no.

At each iteration the variable will be destroyed and your class will be pointing to a dead object.

The program doesn't give a runtime error when executing your code because C++ design philosophy is that a programmer would never do that so checking for it is a waste of time.

What happens when you do this kind of mistake is "undefined behavior", the worst possible thing it can happen in this case is that the program apparently seems working anyway (just to bite you back later).

Answer (score 3):

In your loop the lifetime of `foo f` is too short for be user as reference, you should declare it as a pointer

```
...
foo *f = new foo();
f->i = i;
bar* b = new bar;
b->foo_ = f;
...
```